# Change Excel cells format from number to date with Python 3.5

Tags: python, excel, date, xlrd

I need to open the existing Excel file, iterate through the column with dates (showed as numbers - like 42311 etc) and change the format of the cells from numbers to dates (like 16/12/2016). Then save and close the file.

I've tried to search through xlrd documentation and similar questions of other people, but still no understanding.

Comment: `xlrd` is for reading data *out* of Excel files. If you just want to change the format of a column, why are you using Python?

Comment: because I have about 160 excel files and don't want to do it manually

Comment: @electrify, are you still looking to get this done? If so, please add more details to your question. List of file names and column names with integers to change to datetime type would go a long way.